# Why use the Y combinator for recursion?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

The Y combinator is defined as $$Y=\lambda f.(\lambda x. f (x x))(\lambda x. f (x x))$$
It has the following useful property:
$$Y g = g (Y g)$$
for some expression $g$.
It can be easily used to implement a recursive function, e.g. factorial:

```py
Y = lambda f : (lambda x : f(lambda v : x(x)(v)))(lambda x : f(lambda v : x(x)(v)))
F = lambda r : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * r(n - 1)
fact = Y(F) # same as F(Y(F)), therefore the r in the body becomes Y(F) which is fact
print(fact(5))
```

The above code outputs 120, as expected. (The Y combinator in the code differs from the one at the start of the question. This is because the one at the start would cause a recursion depth exception. They are equivalent in the lambda calculus nonetheless)

---

An alternative method, which is the topic of my question, is as follows:

```py
F = lambda r : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * r(r)(n - 1)
fact = F(F) # r gets substituted with F, therefore the expression in the body becomes F(F) which is fact
print(fact(5))
```

This once again outputs 120, but is more readable and straightforward in my opinion.

---

If the second method works, then what is the point of using the Y combinator? [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) says this about the second method:

> …The self-application achieves replication here, passing the function's lambda expression on to the next invocation as an argument value, making it available to be referenced and called there.

> This solves it but requires re-writing each recursive call as self-application. We would like to have a generic solution, without a need for any re-writes:…

It then proposes the first method as a better solution. What do they mean by *generic solution*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of thinking about why $Y$ would be preferable is that it separates 'content' from 'plumbing'. Typical notation for recursive definitions in practical languages is something like:

$$\mathsf{fact} = λn. \mathsf{if}\ n = 0\ \mathsf{then}\ 1\ \mathsf{else}\ n * \mathsf{fact} (n-1)$$

It is desirable to just be able to factor out the body with minimal changes, like:

$$λ \mathsf{fact}\ n. \mathsf{if}\ n = 0\ \mathsf{then}\ 1\ \mathsf{else}\ n * \mathsf{fact} (n-1)$$

We get this simply by adding an argument with the same name as the desired recursive definition; there's no need to change the body. So, it is purely (as can be) the 'content' that distinguishes your recursive definition. Then $Y$ takes care of the 'plumbing' necessary to make $\mathsf{fact}$ actually work like a recursive call and so on.

Your alternate definition has moved some of the plumbing into the content function, by inlining the part where $\mathsf{fact}$ is passed a copy of itself. This replaces $Y$ with the simpler $λf. f f$, but it complicates the content with some of the details of how the looping is being achieved. These details would need to be copied into every content function.

So, $Y$ is preferable in the sense that it confines the implementation details of looping into one function, so that the 'bodies' of recursive definitions can be written in the straight forward way.